# Visual Studio 2015 Error List only showing errors for open files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, error-list

I'm new to Visual Studio 2015. I'm working on porting a solution from VS 2010 to VS 2015 and Entity Framework and I'm working through the compile errors. Unfortunately, to get the error messages to display in the Error List, I have to open the files first. My filter options are "Entire Solution", the show errors is toggled on, warnings are off and "Build + IntelliSense" is selected.

With no files opened, I'm getting 5 errors but when I open one of my files with errors, the list then shows all the errors for that file as well. When I clost the file and rebuild, I'm back to the original 5 error messages. I've tried the different filter options in different combinations but I'm not able to get ALL the compile errors to be displayed. I have to open a few files, fix the compile errors, open a few more, and so on.

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?

Thanks,

Carlo.

Comment: Have you tried toggling filter options from Entire Solution to Only Opened Files, and then back again?  Maybe try CLEANING solution first, or cleaning solution before/after toggling the Error window setting. What kind of project are you porting (web, library, service?)

Comment: Yes, I tried all those. We want to move our 2010 web application to 2015 and move to Entity Framework and MVC. The first step is to convert to Entity Framework so we've taken just the database (DAL) portion and are converting to Entity Framework - Database first. This is what we are working on now and where we are getting the errors that aren't showing up until the file is opened. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

I had similar problem with Code Analysis - VS 2017 Community 15.7.2 - this may be the same issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-enable-and-disable-full-solution-analysis-for-managed-code

To toggle full solution analysis:

1. To open the Options dialog box, on the menu bar in Visual Studio choose Tools > Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, choose Text Editor > C# or Basic > Advanced.
3. Select the Enable full solution analysis check box to enable full solution analysis, or clear the box to disable it. Choose OK when you're done.
   I thought I had no warnings...now I have a few more!

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped when i was porting a library from VB to C# and analysis probably turned itself off , because of too many errors.

Answer (score 0):

As there has been no solution to this thread, I'll add mine which I tested in VS2017 15.5.2 (.NET Core 2.0) and might work with VS2015.

I found all my view-errors, by publishing:

1. In Visual Studio, by right-clicking project and select "Publish". Create a new profile and click "Folder", which will publish your solution to a specified folder and this catches all view-errors, as your views are compiled into a .dll.
2. You can do the same from terminal: `dotnet publish -c release`

I was **not** able to get the output when using the runtime-identifier flag (`dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64`).

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

anyone coming to this issue for VS2022, please try below steps to display Solution-Wide Build-IntelliSense Errors-Warning-Messages:

open **Tools-Options-Text Editor-C#-Advanced**

select **Run background analysis for Entire Solution**

select **Show compiler errors and warning for Entire Solution**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a specific class library project that seemed to be giving all the errors. I removed the project reference and re-added it, that solved it for me. Nothing else seemed to work. Difficult error to reproduce.